# Localytics Integration on android api level below 14

Tags: android, analytics, android-2.3-gingerbread, localytics

I'm trying to implement Localytics in my app. Available docs describes procedure pretty clear, but only for devices with Ice Cream Sandwich and newer. Does anyone know, how to integrate this in an app with API below 14? Appreciate any help.

Best,
Radek

Comment: @2Dee excuse me, as I may be wrong, but only thing I found is a link described as "alternative session management", which points to nowhere (http://docs.localytics.com/dev/android.html#TODO)

Comment: @2Dee If you did actually bother on reading the question you will see there's nothing in the Localytics documentation for API below 14, just an empty link to nowhere. Or you can just shut me by sharing the link. If you are going to take the piss and be a smart-ass let me stop you right there. Radek as you said I can't find anything there so I'd just open a ticket with them.